# Large amount of python multiprocessing causes Memory Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

### Intro

Hi, I'm trying to run a windows OS command in a loop using python 3 multiprocessing, but when the loop gets to big (thousand commands) I'm getting memory errors and the process exits / never completes.

### Why?

I need to run 65,000 commands as fast as possible, and one by one seems non efficient. these commands are a windows normal command (dir is for example).

-- I do not need the results of the command ! just for it to run.

### Code

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def worker(num):
    print("worker:", num)
    subprocess.Popen('dir') # or os.system('dir') for example
    return

def main():
    jobs = []

    for i in list(range(1,65535)):
        i = str(i)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

### Question

What am I doing wrong here? whats the correct way to run a windows OS command multiple times with python (while maintaining any threading).

Comment: No surprise if you are opening more than 65000 processes in a short time. That should bring every OS to its limits.

Comment: As mentioned, you create 1 python process plus the process running the command itself 65K times without ever waiting for anything. Do you want the result from the command for processing? Is there a light or heavy amount of processing involved?

Comment: Let's see, on my system, a regular python process takes about 4 megabytes, so 4e6*65535*1e-9 == 262 gigabytes. Do you expect to have enough memory to handle that? Why do you spawn a python process just to create a subprocess??

Comment: This is a sample code for an exmaple. I have very valid reasons for wanting to run commands on multiple processes.

Comment: My question is what do I have to fix to properly handle this kind of implementation

Comment: Use a processes pool with a decent amount of processes. See the first example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html .

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the number of workers running at the same time.
You can use the `p.is_alive()` to check how many of them are currently running.